# How do I work with Docker images correct?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have the folder "**/home/user/project1**" which contains this docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: docker-user/test-mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_USER=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
```

I created the new project in "**/home/user/project2**" which contains this docker-compose:

```
    version: '3.3'
    services:
      mysql:
        image: docker-user/mytestdb-mysql
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretdb
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=mytestdb
          - MYSQL_USER=mytestdb
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysecretdb
        command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        volumes:
          - db:/var/lib/mysql
```

After exec command **docker-compose up -d**, I cannot login my mysql in **project2** with new password and username. But if I use the old password from **project1**, it works!

Why I cannot login with new password and username in **project2**?

I use in **project1** and **project2** same image: **mysql:5.7.22**

Comment: What command do you run to access mysql service in project2? By the way, you wrote that you use the same image, but in project1 you got `docker-user/test-mysql` and in project2 `docker-user/mytestdb-mysql`.

Comment: @norbjd Yes, it is a just a different name, but it has same base layer mysql:5.7.22 in Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy the "/home/user/project1/db" folder to ""/home/user/project2"?
Since it is mounted, the credentials would be the same as for project1.
Change/comment the volume section in the compose file and test it for once.

Comment: Great. @coderfire Do accept the answer since it works well already.